# Convert integer to dates

Tags: java, datetime

I'm stuck at this part where I must use integer to get the individual year, month ,day, hour and min to string it into a date format, e.g. 24/01/2004 13:00.

```
Date Date = (years,month,day,hour,min);// error Part 
System.out.println(Date);
```

Comment: use setters of Date class

Comment: well you have to use `new Date(year,month,day,hour,min)` but this is deprecated best use `Calendar.set`

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Calendar#set(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,int,int,int,int%29)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year,month-1,day,hour,min);//month is 0 based
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: This is better than the others because you avoid strings and string parsing (as with DateFormat), which is cumbersome, and you avoid deprecated methods. +1

Answer (score 1):

The [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is very practical to create Dates just the way you were looking for:

```
// omission of DateTimeZone parameter results in use of JVM default time zone
DateTime dt = new DateTime( years, month, day, hour, min, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" ) );
Date date = dt.toDate();
```

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: I would add a mention of time zone. The code shown uses the JVM's default time zone. Usually best to specify the [time zone by name](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). Simply pass a time zone object at the end of the constructor: `new DateTime( 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" ) )`. A java.util.Date object has no time zone (it is UTC/GMT), and Joda-Time's `toDate` method will handle the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of link below to Set attributes of Date class.

```
Date releaseDate = new Date();
releaseDate.setYear(year);
releaseDate.setMonth(month);
......
releaseDate.setMinutes(min);
```

Refer Java docs [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
.
.
.

DateFormat formatData = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy H:mm");
System.out.println(formatData.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a headstart on Java 8, you could use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)'s [LocalDateTime class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html), which shares quite a few method signatures with the [Java 8 LocalDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).  Though unfortunately it doesn't have `LocalDateTime.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute)` or similar methods; instead, use the constructors.

Comment: LocalDateTime means no time zone. Think twice if you truly want to time zone.

Comment: Not no time zone: the local time zone.  Which is what I inferred from the OPs question, since there is no time zone mentioned.  You can't have no time zone if you're talking year, month, day etc., since those concepts require a time zone to make sense.

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood those classes. From Joda-Time doc you linked: `LocalDateTime is … a datetime without a time zone.` From Java 8 doc you linked: `A date-time without a time-zone`. Think of "LocalDateTime" as always being in UTC/GMT no matter what (no time zone offset). They are called "Local" in the sense of "I only care about one single time zone (presumably my own local time zone) and I promise to never ever want to adjust this object to another time zone.". Naïve programmers tend to think they want this, but later regret it. Thus my cautioning comment.

Comment: To use your JVM's **default** time zone, simply omit a time zone object when instantiating a DateTime (Joda-Time) or ZonedDateTime (Java 8). `myDateTime = new DateTime();` or `myZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();`

Comment: Ah yes, closer reading does prove you right.  LocalDateTime is a potential pitfall then.  However if you're using with only very limited scope, and in particular if you're not persisting it to a DB where anyone might get their hands on it, then its simplicity is a redeeming feature.

Comment: Yes, you’ve got it now. In practice, the "Local" classes are generally the wrong choice. "Local" = "Ignoring The Issue Of Time Zones". Trying to ignore time zones will come back to bite you eventually. At least that’s my experience in business-world software.